# What is deleting my Tag?

Tags: hooks, tags

I've run into this twice this month and scratching my head. Read this image upside down: We hit post create Address hook -> my regex extension creates a Tag - all good; happy dance; then something in Core deletes my Tag :-( why?

[image]

Comment: At some point it must be calling a SQL query with the words `delete` and `tag` in the query. Assuming it's coming from the civi side somewhere can you put a hack in CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery to do a case insensitive check for those words in the query and then log a debug_backtrace()? That might not catch it but it might.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like your extension is deleting the entity tag?

Comment: No - it’s not the extension -the extension just prints all hooks that are invoked but the actual post delete tag happens elsewhere. It’s something like: post create address hook is invoked before post create individual hook - contact_id does exist when this post create address hook is invoked (in a memory layer perhaps?) - so it does let me create the tag (API call is happy) but then shortly after some bits are purged/cleaned up and my tag is deleted;